# Implementing authentication and authorization using OWIN

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I try to create authentication and authorization for my single page web-api project.

For this purpose I red this cool [article](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) from **Taiseer Joudeh**.

But the problem is that in my project I have database with tables and I want to adopt **OWIN** to work with my **existing tables**.

Maybe someone knows useful article or post on which I can rely for this subject?

Comment: When you say you have existing database with existing tables, are you talking about User Account specific tables?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be looking at creating a custom Identity storage provider. Read the following as a starting point: https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity.

Comment: Is there any advantage over OWIN ?

Comment: This is still on the OWIN middleware.